# CSS Won't work in webpage

Tags: html, css, web

In my style sheet I have some rules defined to essentially place an object in the center of the screen. My div classes simply will not format my text.

Code for Web Page

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  color: BLACK;
}
.active {} .wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lane="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The "How Drunk Do You Want to Be?" Machine</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The best damn webpage you have ever seen">
  <meta name="Jarred Parr" content="drinking games">

  <link rel="Style Sheet" type="text/css" href="Style Sheet.css">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#b3b3cc">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <button class="button">Button</button>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but your code works perfectly fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yfhcL4g6/

Answer (score 3):

Just correct your css external file link tag:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "Style Sheet.css">
```

Comment: Why is the `type="text/css"` necessary?

Comment: From HTML5 the type="text/css" is now optional.
You can just type <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style Sheet.css"/>                    The attribute specifies the style sheet language of the element's contents and overrides the default style sheet language.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML and CSS are correct (although most of your CSS is unnecessary). Run the snippet below with your trimmed CSS and you'll see that it's working.

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

My guess is that the reference to your stylesheet (the `link` tag) is not correct. Spaces in filenames are troublesome at best, and usually cause all sorts of havoc. Rename your stylesheet without the space and verify that it resides in the same directory as your HTML file.

Comment: It's **not** correct. The value of the `rel` attribute is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

correct your css link tag i think its wrong that's why its unable to call your css file . `

```
<link rel= "Style Sheet" type= "text/css" href= "Style Sheet.css">
```

It should be something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/sheet.css"> 
 /* path means where you kept your css file/directory  and /your css name*/
```

and If you kept the css file in the same folder there is no need to add path and it will be  simply

```
<link rel= "StyleSheet" type= "text/css" href= "StyleSheet.css">
```

for HTML5 you don't need `type= "text/css"`

but below Htm5 sometimes it's needed

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that `button` is a native html type and not a class. So you don't need the period to target it in CSS. Also, since absolute positioning is the opposite of dynamically centering, you can't use that. You'll need to set its margin to auto and display to either block or flex.

Also, most importantly, make sure your reference to the `stylesheet` is correct. It should be lower cased with no spaces, and you probably want a path unless it's in the same directory:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
```

```css
button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <button>Button</button>

</div>
```

Comment: These may be useful pointers, but they don't address the problem of why things were not working at all.